# Numbering rectangles in 2D space to satisfy monotonicity

Tags: python, database, numpy, geometry, kdtree

Given a set of data points (1000 in this case) in 2D space, I run a KD-tree algorithm to generate bounding boxes of approximately equal size. From `sklearn`:

```
import sklearn

lst # 1000 points
sklearn.KDTree(lst, leaf_size=30)
```

For each rectangle, I want to know if there is a way to number (or index) the rectangles such that all points contained within rectangle A are smaller than all points contained in rectangle B if the point (x,y) in B is greater than (x', y') in A. If there is, is this method extendable to higher dimensions?

In other words, B's mapping > A's mapping if x > x' and y > y'.

I have considered using sorting by a distance of the bottom corner, sort by distance for the top corner, but there always seems to be an issue with the middleboxes.

Take for example:

[image: attached]

Boxes have their numbering annotated on the right of the top-left corner. This was created by sorting distance from the top-right corner.

For box 14 to 13, there are points that belong in 13 that have all their coordinates greater than box 14, which isn't what I want. Here is an explanation in picture form:

[image: Here]

If 13 and 14 were switched, this method might work in general, but I don't know if that's provable.

Here is the pseudocode in python for how I've run this code.

```
import numpy as np
# mins is the bottom_left corner of a box
# maxs is the top_right corner of a box
# data is the data points that belongs in the box described by mins[i], maxs[i]

mins, maxs, data

distances = [distance(i, [0]*2) for i in maxs]
sort_indices = np.argsort(distances)
mins = mins[sort_indices]
maxs = maxs[sort_indices]
data = [data[i] for i in sort_indices]

# Draw mins, maxs, and data with matplotlib.
```

Comment: "I run a KD-tree algorithm to generate bounding boxes of approximately equal size." What is size? Area, perimiter, number of points?

Comment: Can you use a grid instead of differently shaped bounding boxes? If yes, then you could use z-ordering (morton-order) to enumerate the grid boxes. Z-ordering would fulfill your ordering/enumeration requirement.

Comment: I've used the grid based method before, so I'd like to use this numbering of disjoint bounding boxes to accomplish the same thing.